# Jenkins not recognizing the git sub-directory

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins, just trying to build/run my first Spring boot application.

This is my sample git repository url, which I am trying to load in to Jenkins.

https://github.com/LogeshLohit/thymeleaf-sb-test.git

I checked-out the application like this,
[image]

While I am trying to build the application it throws this error "[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\Program Files\Jenkins_new\workspace\path1). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]"

In my local repository the project is located at "D:\Program Files\Jenkins_new\workspace\path1\thymeleaf-test", but jenkins only looks at "D:\Program Files\Jenkins_new\workspace\path1"(from the logs) I guess.

How can I make Jenkins to look one folder down, so that it will find the pom.xml in its sub-directory?

Comment: How are you invoking maven step? Is this a freestyle project?

Comment: Yes. That's a freestyle project, building with "invoke top-level maven targets" and goal as "compile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the invoke top-level maven target step, click Advanced ...
POM   [`rel_path/to/pom.xml`]
relative to workspace root. In your case, that's `thymeleaf-test/pom.xml`

I suppose it should also be possible to invoke using a [command line option](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html):
 `-f,--file <arg>`
Force the use of an alternate POM file (or directory with pom.xml).

Answer (score 1):

> That's a freestyle project, building with "invoke top-level maven targets" and goal as "compile"

You might at least specify the full path (or relative path, as commented) of the pom.xml, as [seen in "How To Execute Maven Project Using Jenkins"](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/install-jenkins-14.png):

[image: https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/install-jenkins-14.png]

Comment: An explicit full path is not necessary; relative path will do. Full path will also cause problems where multiple nodes are not all identically configured. As an alternative, consider the Jenkins variable `${WORKSPACE}` instead.